# How to run GhostScript on AS400 server

Tags: ghostscript

We have PDF files on the AS/400 and we need to convert them to PCL for printing . So for this we found Ghostscript for converting  PDF file to PCL format , so we're looking for a way to run  Ghostscript commands on the AS/400.

Have you please any idea how to do it , if no  I am looking for another "free" method to do what we need.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

*Ghostscript* doesn't accept PCL as input, you need Ghostpdl for that, and more specifically the pcl6 executable.

You can't 'run Ghostscript commands' you can run the executable with the PCL file as an input and suitable command line switches.

In order to do this you will need to compile Ghostscript for your target environment (AS/400 apparently). Ghostscript is written in standard C so you will need a C compiler, the build process is convoluted and requires running a number of executables in order to generate some platform specific files.

Your first task is going to be porting Ghostscript and its build process onto your target platform. I'm not aware of anyone having done this for AS/400 but we'd be interested to hear how you get on.